# Body is too large (content gets out of box) and enables right scroll

Tags: css, width

Tried a lot of ways and a lot of Codes, but its not working website width does not stay in screen. Always enables space to the right side and content is bigger than screen.

tried width and height 100vw; max-width: 100%;
also tried giving the body a specific width

```
`body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: solid; 
  padding-left: 2px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0px;
}`
```

```
<
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Try</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="galery.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-wrapper">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="/Users/Desktop/Website/images/AdobeStock_491355559.jpeg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href="grafikdesign.html">Stuff</a></div>
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href="underpage24.html">About</a></div>
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="contact.html">contact</a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please also show your html

Comment: As it stands your code (plus some minimal HTML) does not show the problem so please produce a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example